# IPsec tunnel blocks after a while without error. Where to find details?

Tags: debian, ipsec, openswan

There is an IPsec Tunnel created with OpenSwan that works perfectly well packets going through answers received etc until at some point in time traffic stops.

I can regenerate the tunnel doing

```
ipsec auto --down tunnelName
ipsec auto --up tunnelName
```

But eventually it will collapse again, sometimes after hours sometimes after days.
I am not able to find any error messages for example in pluto.log that indicate that the tunnel collapsed, the last lines found are the ones reporting Quick_Mode entry.

Our side: Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, Linux Openswan U2.6.38/K3.13.0-91-generic (netkey)

Other side: SAP Router and unknown firewall

I tapped this using tcpdump while the tunnel was not doing its job:

```
10:30:53.357186 IP us.isakmp > them.isakmp: isakmp: phase 1 I ident
10:30:53.384168 IP them.isakmp > us.isakmp: isakmp: phase 1 R ident
10:30:53.384880 IP us.isakmp > them.isakmp: isakmp: phase 1 I ident
10:30:53.425034 IP them.isakmp > us.isakmp: isakmp: phase 1 R ident
10:30:53.425770 IP us.isakmp > them.isakmp: isakmp: phase 1 I ident[E]
10:30:53.451727 IP them.isakmp > us.isakmp: isakmp: phase 1 R ident[E]

10:32:01.089957 IP us > them: ESP(spi=0x6e51327d,seq=0x14b), length 100
10:32:02.089097 IP us > them: ESP(spi=0x6e51327d,seq=0x14c), length 100
```

First part seems to be a succesful tunnel rekey negotiation second part two failing requests, or not?

Netstat says that requests sent into the tunnel reach nothing more than `SYN_SENT` and then time out.

Are there any other logs I could search as I am not allowed to debug the other end of the tunnel?

Comment: Please update the post telling us the OS and versions in both points if possible and the version of openswan.

Comment: Of course. Sorry I forgot. Stage fright :-)

Comment: Do you have any ideia how long it takes to collapse? Could it be due to timeouts of inactivity on the firewall on their side after a fixed allotted time? Could it be some parameter that is missing in the ipsec config? have a look at /var/syslog too. (I am using strongswan here with charon)

Comment: As I updated above the time the tunnel takes to collapse is highly variable. I will have a look at syslog. To be honest I simply hope I can find some evidence so I can force the owner of the other side to do their job :-/

Comment: Of course I am not allowed to ping :-( However I will try to create some kind of keep-alive. Could you post this idea as an answer so that I can acknowledge your efforts?

Comment: Interesting, as I supposed there appears to be some sort of compatibility/configuration problem.  what does `sudo ipsec status` says when it is trying to renegotiate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `/var/log/syslog`, usually there is a trove of logs to be found there relating to ipsec.

There used to be a (very) old bug talking with Windows on the other side due to inactivity...a simple ping in the background fixed that, or a patch); cannot remember the specifics though.

Nevertheless, most firewalls have a default timeout rule where if the connection is inactive more than a certain time they will tear down the connection. However, it is supposed to be negotiated again, except if some parameter is off, or due to some odd compatibility problem.

Comment: I was just wanting to accept the answer, when the tunnel came tumbling down again. I will take another tour of syslog as you suggested. The good thing is that the I know now far better when the tunnel ceased to operate -.-

Comment: Collect some and send to the other team. It might be interesting to cross reference time logs (or not). Back in here, I have a central syslog collector with logs over a year to peruse when debugging a problem.

Comment: The human solution :-) The keep alive requests annoyed the IT on the other side so much, that they fixed the problem. I will post the solution here if I can get them to tell me.